# Multiple Nested Dictionaries with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to import this kind of JSON response into Pandas? Ive been trying to get it usable with json_normalize but I can't seem to get more than one level to work at a time ( I can get notes but can't being in custom_fields). I also cannot figure out how to call out something like ['reporter']['name'] (which should be jdoe). This is from Mantis and its the JSON output of a requests response. Im now wondering if it needs to br broken up into multiple frames and put back together, or should I use a for loop and put the data I want into a better format for PD to import?

In my head each item should be a column in the series all tied to the id column like this.

```
id | summary | project.name | reporter.name ..|.. custom.fields.Project_Stage | ... notes1.reporter.name | notes1.text ... notes2.reporter.name | notes2.text



{
  "issues": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "summary": "Some text",
      "project": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "North America"
      },
      "category": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Retail"
      },
      "reporter": {
        "id": 1099,
        "name": "jdoe"
      },
      "custom_fields": [
        {
          "field": {
            "id": 107,
            "name": "Product Escalations"
          },
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "field": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Project_Stage"
          },
          "value": "Pending"
        }
      ],
      "notes": [
        {
          "id": 214288,
          "reporter": {
            "id": 9999,
            "name": "jdoe"
          },
          "text": "Worked with Mark over e-mail",
          "view_state": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "public",
            "label": "public"
          },
          "type": "note",
          "created_at": "2020-12-04T15:55:02-08:00",
          "updated_at": "2020-12-04T15:55:02-08:00"
        },
        {
          "id": 214289,
          "reporter": {
            "id": 9999,
            "name": "jdoe"
          },
          "text": "I attempted on numerous occasions to setup a meeting with him to set it up for him.",
          "view_state": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "public",
            "label": "public"
          },
          "type": "note",
          "created_at": "2020-12-04T15:57:02-08:00",
          "updated_at": "2020-12-04T15:57:02-08:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what the DF would look like in my head. All the data for one ticket on one line/series.

[image: Sample DataFrame]

Comment: kindly post a dataframe of your expected output

Comment: Whats the best way to do that @sammywemmy?

Comment: create a table maybe excel or a notepad with the headers and values for each row. copy and paste into your question. It will guide SO folks to answer your question appropriately, and remove guesswork

Answer (score 0):

Those structures with many lists at the same level are tricky. Try flatten_json. https://github.com/amirziai/flatten

If you're response is called 'dic', you can use this.

```
from flatten_json import flatten
dic_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in dic['issues'])
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)
```

Output

```
     id    summary  project.id   project.name  category.id category.name  ...  notes.1.view_state.id notes.1.view_state.name  notes.1.view_state.label notes.1.type         notes.1.created_at         notes.1.updated_at
0  1234  Some text           1  North America           11        Retail  ...                     10                  public                    public         note  2020-12-04T15:57:02-08:00  2020-12-04T15:57:02-08:00

In [101]: df.columns
Out[101]:
Index(['id', 'summary', 'project.id', 'project.name', 'category.id',
       'category.name', 'reporter.id', 'reporter.name',
       'custom_fields.0.field.id', 'custom_fields.0.field.name',
       'custom_fields.0.value', 'custom_fields.1.field.id',
       'custom_fields.1.field.name', 'custom_fields.1.value', 'notes.0.id',
       'notes.0.reporter.id', 'notes.0.reporter.name', 'notes.0.text',
       'notes.0.view_state.id', 'notes.0.view_state.name',
       'notes.0.view_state.label', 'notes.0.type', 'notes.0.created_at',
       'notes.0.updated_at', 'notes.1.id', 'notes.1.reporter.id',
       'notes.1.reporter.name', 'notes.1.text', 'notes.1.view_state.id',
       'notes.1.view_state.name', 'notes.1.view_state.label', 'notes.1.type',
       'notes.1.created_at', 'notes.1.updated_at'],
      dtype='object')
```